# Rest Api Rest Get ID value

Tags: acumatica

I would like to get the ID and not the value of the status field :

https://xrp-flex.cegid.cloud/belong/entity/FFY/20.200.001/Salesorder?$

```
"Status": {"value": "Open"},
```

I would like have this :

```
"Status": {"value": "N"},
```

Thanks Xav

Comment: REST API replaces the ID with labels for the String Lists by default. You will need to create a custom GI with the specific data that you need to get it.